# Executing command, getting output and using it

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to do a Windows batch file that excecute a command and pass to it a flow param that is received as a parameter of the batch file, then I need to get the output of this execution and do something with it before sending it to the batch output (cuting the output to get the first character only). 
This is what I have so far:

```
for /f %%i in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\JAM Software\SpamAssassin for Windows\spamc.exe" < %1') do set RES2 = %%i
ECHO %RES2~0,1%
```

But it is not working as I expect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're missing a **:** %RES2:~0,1%

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with I'm missing that. :)

Comment: What you have is invalid syntax. You need to have `%RES2:~0,1%` Notice the **:** before the **~**.

Comment: It is still not working, it says something like "< was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %%i in (
    '"C:\Program Files (x86)\JAM Software\SpamAssassin for Windows\spamc.exe" ^< %1'
) do set RES2=%%i
ECHO %RES2:~0,1%
```

There are three changes in your code. The colon in the echo line (needed, it is part of the sintax), the escaped redirection and the spaces removed around the equal sign in the set line. With spaces, the variable name contains a space and the value inside the variable also have a space in it (and it will be the first, so the later echo command will fail)

Comment: first thanks for the reply, I still have some problems. For example should I put an ^ character before <? If I do this I get another error like: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @yosoy, sorry, missed it. Use `'call "c:\Program Files ...."`, and yes, the redirection operador should be escaped.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!, now it it working, I did what you advice and just add some params I missed and it's working! :)